# How to set text alignment on a column of QTableView programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

So far the only solution I have found is to subclass QItemDelegate and implement my alignment rule in the paint() function. Is it really the simplest way?

I am using the C++ API.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The alternative to subclussing `QItemDelegate` is to subclass your model and override `data()` method.

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
    if (index.column() == yourCellIndex && role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole) {
        return Qt::AlignLeft;
    } else {
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

Comment: "return QVariant();"  did not work in my case, only empty lines were displayed. It only worked if one writes:     "return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index,role);"
Provided the model is QSqlRelationalTableModel (or the name of the model class)

Answer (score 3):

```
QSqlTableModel *model2= new QSqlTableModel();

model2->setTable("Save");
model2->select();

QSortFilterProxyModel *proxy1=new QSortFilterProxyModel();
proxy1->setSourceModel(model2);

QStandardItemModel *modd=new QStandardItemModel();

for (int z =0; z< proxy1->rowCount(); ++z)
   {
    for (int y =0; y< proxy1->columnCount(); ++y)
        {
        QStandardItem *item= new QStandardItem();
        item->setText(proxy1->index(z,y).data().toString());
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        modd->setItem(z,y,item);

        }
  }
ui->tableView->setModel(modd);
```

Comment: `item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); work well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me: [Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setTextAlignment)

```
void MainWindow::fillTable()
{
    sudukoItem->setText( "qq" );
    sudukoItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    sudukoModel->appendRow( sudukoItem );
    sudukoTable->setModel( sudukoModel );

    sudukoTable->setRowHeight( ( sudukoModel->rowCount() - 1 ), 100 );
    sudukoTable->setColumnWidth( ( sudukoModel->columnCount() - 1 ), 100 );
}
```

Where:

```
QTableView*         sudukoTable;
QStandardItemModel* sudukoModel;
QModelIndex*        modelIndex;

QStandardItem*      sudukoItem;
```

Credit goes to this comment: [How to set text alignment on a column of QTableView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958893/how-to-set-text-alignment-on-a-column-of-qtableview-programmatically#comment86076564_30663201)

> `item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);` work well for me. – Ratah