# QTableView cell text alignment - changing without iterating

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Is there a better way of changing a column text alignment? I'm iterating through all the cells in the column:

```
for r in range(self.rowCount()):
    self.item(r, column).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
```

Isn't there a better (more straightforward) way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like this was answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958893/how-to-set-text-alignment-on-a-column-of-qtableview-programatically

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would fit into the rest of your code, but have you looked at the setColumnAlignment() method?

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgraphicsgridlayout.html#setColumnAlignment

Seems like this would do it.

Comment: Such a method would be great but unfortunately it isn't a member of QTableWidget. Thanks anyway!